# Can we create the class library (dll) without giving namespace in code in .net framework?

Tags: c#, dll, class-library

I have a doubt in creating class library in .net. I saw in one class library code that they didn't use the namespace in it. But still its compiled and run successfully when I  use the method in other classes. So can you please tell me what is the advantage, disadvantage of it?

Is there any specific reason to not mentioning the namespace in class library?

Answer (score 1):

The choice is yours, both can be used.

If you do not use namespace then you have to retype the namespace names repeatedly in every call function, so it is not efficient because it makes the function name too long.

Types are organized into **namespace** to **avoid naming conflicts** and **make type names easier to find**.

Example:

> A. Without namespace

Namespace + method (it's long and namespace are always used repeatedly)

```
System.Security.Cryptography.RSA rsa = System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Create();
```

> B. With namespace

Namespace (once declaration, on top of class)

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

Method (it's simple)

```
RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
```

Comment: i think you missed what he was asking

Answer (score 1):

Namespace is like a book shelf in library you can store the books in the shelf so when you want a specific book you know where to look  i.e imagine you need two classes in code like Home.cs and about.cs

now if they dont have namespace you have to do something like

```
using yourFolderPath.home
using yourFolderPath.about
```

now if you have a name space then

```
using namespace
```

Plus namespace become morre importent once you jumps to n-tier arch where you have a different Layer for your DataComponent ie models

Answer (score 1):

I believe the OP is asking about the use of the "namespace" keyword in the class library file itself.  If your class library file only contains a single class, the namespace keyword isn't necessary.  You can just have your using statements at the top of the file and then the class definition itself, not enclosed in a namespace.  If your library file contains more than one class definition, it's best to enclose those definitions in a namespace.

Example -- Library file with a single class definition:

```
using System;
// Additional using statements here
public class MySingleClass
{
    // Class definition here
}
```

Example -- Multiple classes in a library file:

```
using System;
// Additional using statements here

namespace Vehicles
{
    public class Car
    {
        // Class definition here
    }

    public class Boat
    {
        // Class definition here
    }

    public class Airplane
    {
        // Class definition here
    }
}
```